# Filter special symbols such as (!@#$%..etc) except for "+" and "-" in numbers

Tags: python

I am designing a calculator to increase my knowledge in python. Is there a way to filter any symbols in numbers while not filtering these symbols "+" "-". I personally don't want to resort to using lists and typing up every single symbols available. If it is the only way let me know.

in this code I used alnum() to filter the symbols but it is including "+" and "-". Is there a way to create exceptions for these?

```
variable = "-13"

if variable.isalnum():
    print("yes")

else:
    print("no")
```

```
current output: 
"no"
>>>
```

```
output wanted:
"yes"
```

Comment: Well, what is the rule that tells you whether a symbol counts as "special" or not? " Is there a way to create exceptions for these?" Well, how do you normally create special rules for things in Python? (Hint: how do you make the code do something differently `if` a condition is true?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `+` and `-` then check the remainder for the characters you want. Regular expressions let you replace multiple characters at once.

```
import re
variable = "-13"

if re.sub("[+-]", "", variable).isalnum():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Regular expressions have a special character class that will match alphanumerics plus the underscore. If you don't mind adding the underscore to your lexicon, you could do

```
import re
variable = "-13"

if re.match(r"[\w+-]+$", variable):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

You can put this into a function and run a set of tests to see if it meets your goal with multiple strings. I collapsed the if/else into a single statement for brevity.

```
import re

def validator(variable):
    match = "yes" if re.match(r"[\w+-]+$", variable) else "no"
    print(repr(variable), match)
    return match
    
tests = [("-13", "yes"),
         ("hello-13", "yes"),
         ("%13", "no"),
         ("+", "yes"),
         ("-", "yes"),
         ("hello + 13", "no"),
         ("", "no")]

for val, result in tests:
    assert validator(val) == result
```

Comment: How would I still keep getting the output of "yes" when the variable = "+" or "-" now?

Comment: @Helpmepls - I added test cases for + and - and they worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check each char individually:

```py
is_ok = True
for char in variable:
    if not char.isalnum() and char not in "-+":
        is_ok = False
        break
if is_ok:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Additionally, are you sure you want to be using `isalnum`? I'd recommend `isdigit` ([tutorial](https://lerner.co.il/2019/02/17/pythons-str-isdigit-vs-str-isnumeric/))

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, this has been bugging me for hours

Comment: If it solved it for you, please accept as an answer, using the green checkark

Answer (score 0):

You may use this try-except scenario:

```
variable = "-13"
try:
    num = int(variable) 
    print("yes") 
except:
    print("no")
```